# How to change default port 1521 for oracle database?

Tags: oracle, docker

I already have oracle 11g installed in my windows. I was trying to use oracle docker image. I downloaded Oracle Database Enterprise Edition image from docker hub using

```
docker pull store/oracle/database-enterprise:12.2.0.1
```

But after that, when I try to run my container using

```
docker run -d -p 1521:1521 --name oracle store/oracle/database-enterprise:12.2.0.1
```

I get this error message

```
docker: Error response from daemon: Ports are not available: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:1521: bind: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.
```

From what I understand, this is happening because my oracle 11g is already using this port. Is there any way to run my docker container without removing the locally installed Oracle 11g ?

Comment: Just change your docker port mapping rule: `-p 1522:1521`

Comment: What is the valid range for the first part ? I don't have much knowledge about network ports